# Почему так отображается картинка в Opere?

Tags: opera, вёрстка

Всем привет. У меня есть такой код:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
</head>
<div id="header">
<img src="img/logo.png" height="68"/><img src="http://igrun.com/banners/ban-468-6.gif" style="background-color: white; float: right;" width="468" height="68"/>
</div>
```

И вот там в шапке у меня должен быть отображено лого, а с права баннер, так вот во всех браузерах (FF, Google) работает отлично, а вот Опера капризничает и спихивает баннер вниз, под синюю рамку. Скажите, как это исправить?

Скрин:

[image: alt image]

Comment: нужен скрин.Поставте Div#header{overflow:hidden} если поможет то вам сюда
http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/plavayushchie-elementy

Comment: Нет он вообще исчез, вот содержание div'a

    #header{
    background-color: #4169E1;
    height: 68px;
    overflow:hidden
}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RmN5L/ у меня в опере 12.01 не съезжает

Comment: попробуй поменять местами в коде картинки 
<img src="http://igrun.com/banners/ban-468-6.gif" style="background-color: white; float: right;" width="468" height="68"/>
<img src="img/logo.png" height="68"/>

Comment: допишите к первой картинке float: left